# Url Encoding in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am confused about what is supposed to be encoded and when and when it gets decoded. For example:

```
           <%=Html.ActionLink("Login","Login",
            new {controller="Account", returnUrl=HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl})%>
```

on the login page the address will be as follows:

```
            /Account/Login?returnUrl=%2FPreviousDirectory
```

suddenly this will not take me back after filling in credentials and instead takes me to root directory. however, it was working fine before.

My question is regarding the "%2F". Is this the default behavior or did I mess something up? Does this need to be decoded?

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876670/how-to-use-asp-net-mvc-html-helpers-from-a-custom-helper/876681#876681) should show you how to do it.